# Does Selenium work with Java 16? The jars are all there and yet the imports don't work

Tags: java, selenium, geckodriver, java-16

Learning Selenium from a relatively-beginner Java background.  Downloaded the JARs and imported them to Eclipse as per all the guides, but they don't have any bearing on the functionality of the code.  Searched the web high and low, but can't find anything unless I'm going crazy.  Screenshot attached to show the referenced libraries as well as the code: [code and jars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiq9E.png)

Code itself is:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
public class Firefox {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        //comment the above 2 lines and uncomment below 2 lines to use Chrome
        //System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","G:\\chromedriver.exe");
        //WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        
        String baseUrl = "http://demo.guru99.com/test/newtours/";
        String expectedTitle = "Welcome: Mercury Tours";
        String actualTitle = "";

        // launch Fire fox and direct it to the Base URL
        driver.get(baseUrl);

        // get the actual value of the title
        actualTitle = driver.getTitle();

        /*
         * compare the actual title of the page with the expected one and print
         * the result as "Passed" or "Failed"
         */
        if (actualTitle.contentEquals(expectedTitle)){
            System.out.println("Test Passed!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Test Failed");
        }
       
        //close Fire fox
        driver.close();

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you convert that to maven project and check ?

Comment: What happens if you run this code? Or is the problem that your import fails?

Comment: or Probably can you refresh the project and see if they go away

Comment: @MTilsted It says "Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Unable to derive module descriptor for C:\Users\SHEZER\Downloads\selenium-java-3.141.59\selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar
Caused by: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: Provider class org.eclipse.jetty.http.Http1FieldPreEncoder not in module"

The red lines under the imports are what leads me to believe it's the problem

Comment: @cruisepandey will give it a go

Answer (score 1):

Not related to Java, it seems to me that you downloaded wrong library, should be `Selenium Client` not `Selenium Server`

[image]

You can download here, and choose version you want.
https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/